# Custom setters & getters vs ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class ActivityLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, presence: true
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, numericality: true
  belongs_to :user

  def self.log(action, instance)
    ActivityLog.create(
      user_id: instance.user.id,
      instance_id: instance.id,
      action: action
      )
  end

  def action
    actions[:action]
  end

  def action=(action)
    write_attribute(:action, actions.index(action))
  end

  def actions
    ['start','stop','create','destroy']
  end

end
```

I am trying to substitute the keywords defined in `def actions` in the interface layer of the module, but save an integer in the database.

I have the following concerns:

- `def actions` I believe should be defined on the class, but I'm not sure how to call it then from the instance.
- How do I get it to write to the db?
- What should be in `private`?

Comment: Have you considered enums? If you have Rails 4.1 it comes with support: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way of doing this is using constant:

```
class ActivityLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, presence: true
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, numericality: true
  belongs_to :user

  ACTIONS = ['start','stop','create','destroy']

  def self.log(action, instance)
    ActivityLog.create(
      user_id: instance.user.id,
      instance_id: instance.id,
      action: action
      )
  end

  def action
    ACTIONS[:action]
  end

  def action=(action)
    write_attribute(:action, ACTIONS.index(action))
  end

end
```

If you're running rails 4.1 you can use `enum`:

```
class ActivityLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, presence: true
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, numericality: true
  belongs_to :user

  enum action: ['start','stop','create','destroy']

  def self.log(action, instance)
    ActivityLog.create(
      user_id: instance.user.id,
      instance_id: instance.id,
      action: action
      )
  end     
end

ActivityLog.actions  #=> ['start','stop','create','destroy']
a = ActivityLog.new
a.status = 'start'
a.status             #=> 'start'
a.start?             #=> true
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This enum looks very clever, but it throws the following error: You tried to define an enum named "action" on the model "ActivityLog", but this will generate a class method "create", which is already defined by Active Record.

Comment: Ah, true. Enum tries to define a scope for each option. You are left with first option then.